# How do I scale an element relative to the Visual Viewport (and not the Layout Viewport) when the on screen keyboard is up?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an element that I want to resize so it exactly fills the visual viewport when the keyboard is expanded, as asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020996/full-screen-html-element-that-scales-with-keyboard-on-mobile-devices):

[image] [image]

In the past, I'd use `height: 100vh` (with some slight modifications for margin). However, [as of Chrome 108](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/), when the onscreen keyboard is open, the *visual* viewport shrinks, but the *layout* viewport stays the same size. Since `100vh` is relative to the layout viewport, the element no longer shrinks when the keyboard opens.

That Chrome blog post gives one solution, adding `interactive-widget=resizes-content` to the meta viewport tag. This *does* work, and I can set the element to `height: 100vh` and cover both cases.

However, I'm wondering if there's another existing CSS-only solution that would work for this case? That is, some kind of viewport-relative unit that is relative to the *visual* viewport instead of the layout viewport?